# Magento 2: Class ParadoxLabs\TokenBase\Model\CardFactory does not exist

Tags: magento2, compilation

When tried to run the compile command I got this error. I run the cache flush, set the permission for var, generated folders but no luck. I don't have this custom module on my project `(ParadoxLabs\TokenBase\Model\CardFactory)`?.this is coming from core files ?? not sure. Any guidelines will be appreciated. Thanks
[image]

Comment: have you tried removing `var/generation` folder ?

Comment: Paradox labs is custom extension provider its not core magento issue may be something wrong with paradox labs module check if module installed properly

Comment: @MohitRane Yes by running following command `sudo rm -R  generated`

Comment: @AdarshShukla When tried to run to disable `ParadoxLabs_TokenBase` module got the error of unknown module.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman is paradox module present on file system you can find in file system as ParadoxLabs_TokenBase check if module exists on file system

Comment: While checking the core files I didn't see ParadoxLabs on root under the `vendor/Magento` directory. Where can I find the module?

Comment: check in `app/code` folder

Comment: @MohitRane No there is no module with the name of ParadoxLabs

Comment: I am using Magento 2.2.4 version.

Comment: use this command `grep -rr1 "ParadoxLabs"` it will find a module name in your root directory

Comment: @MohitRane Thanks,  dear for the help. It has shown the module that using the Paradoxlabs, so Just removed the extension and compilation completed without error.

Comment: I'm adding as an answer since it solved your issue, so you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` command to find where you have used the module `ParadoxLabs_TokenBase`

```
grep -rr1 "ParadoxLabs_TokenBase"
```

**Hope it helps.**